# Как перевести код C# в регулярные выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть код который проверяет строку на то, что в ней есть слова Test1, Test2, но нет слова Test3, как его можно перевести в Regex

```
void Check(string word)
{
   return str.IndexOf(word) != -1;
}

void TestCheck()
{
   if (Check("Test1") && Check("Test2") && !Check("Test3"))
   {
   }
}
```

Хочу переделать на вот это:

```
void TestCheck()
{
   if (new Regex("Тут паттерн, который загружался из файла, а в качестве стандартного паттерна использовался бы код выше, но нужно перевести его в регулярное выражение").IsMath(str))
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут регулярка?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Это чтобы можно было через файл менять на другую проверку, а это как стандартная будет

Comment: Другую проверку? Слова другие или что? Вообще такое делается простым массивом слов и дальше просто сверяется "Есть-ли в данном массиве это слово или нет". Городить регулярку, ну такое себе занятие...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, другое выражение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Я изменил вопрос.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в регулярке можно будет не только проверять на слова, но на размер, я хотел бы это настраивать через файл, а не изменять код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Я Вас  не понимаю.

Comment: _не только проверять на слова, но на размер_ - о, новое требование. Невозможно дать решение неизвестной задачи.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Мне просто нужно проверить строку, на слова Test1 и Test2, но чтобы там не было Test3, с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я знаю, но мне нужно именно через регулярку, без использование массивов!

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - пишите регулярку, тестируйте. Это не так сложно, как кажется.

Comment: Если надо составить регулярное выражение, то прочитание описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Надо привести однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти

Comment: Вы говорите, что проверку можно будет менять, задав новую регулярку в файле. Кто её будет задавать? Пользователь? Ну вот он пусть и думает, как её составить.

Comment: А у вас в коде будет просто `if (regex.IsMatch(input))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^(?=.*Test1)(?=.*Test2)(?!.*Test3).*$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5abet

> **Test1 bmtrmobmt124 Test2 ok**
>
> Test1 omwbtombwomo false
>
> Test1 ombtromormtbo Test false
>
> Test1 owrmobmowbmro Test2 brmtobro Test3 false
>
> **Test1Test2Test4**